# Generate all possible combinations basing on binary string and under some conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, combinations, truthtable

I have to write algorithm that will generate all possible combinations of different binary strings but under some conditions. The combinations are created by:
**Replacing binary "1" with "00"**

Other conditions:

1. Input binary string, if contains 0, they are in pairs always, so "00"
2. The output also can contain 0 only in pairs

Example:

```
Input:
11

Output:
001
100
0000
11
```

In above example, there is no `010`, because as mentioned earlier, the "0" must have a pair (another "0")

Note that if given binary string contains "00", we don't change them to 1.

In other words, the algorithm should determine how many different binary strings can be created by replacing "1" with "00" (but under the conditions present above), for given binary string and returns all the possible combinations.

I tried O(n^2) algorithm, recursion but can't achieve my goal :/
That's my code:

```
void get_combinations(const std::string& bin, std::set<std::string>& result) {
    result.insert(bin);
    for (int i = 0; i < bin.length(); i++) {
        std::string local_combination = bin;
        for (int j = i; j < bin.length(); j++) {
            if (local_combination[j] == '1') {
                local_combination[j] = '0';
                local_combination.insert(j, "0");

                result.insert(local_combination);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works e.g. for simple input `10`, `01`. But for input `11`, the output doesn't contain `0000`. For "longer" inputs, like `1111` it gives completely bad output.

Comment: _"can't achieve my goal "_  What is your goal?  What is your question?

Comment: But the goal is present in question... "In other words, the algorithm should..."

Comment: ... and you also state "I did O(n^2) algorithm".  Does that mean you achieved your goal?

Comment: I modified it. I tried to do it, but it wasn't work as expected.

Comment: Consider making an [edit] to this question to include what you tried, what exactly didn't work, and what your question is.  It's currently unclear what your specific, focused question is.   Perhaps you are asking someone to write the program you describe?  That would not be on-topic here.

Comment: I have added my current not working code in question

Comment: Your code as it stands seems to consist of: change all 1s from the first occurrence onward and insert, then change all 1s from the second occurrence onward and insert, then change all 1s from the third occurrence onward and insert, etc. That doesn't work. Try building up sets of successively increasing-length strings by dealing with one character of ```bin``` at a time, inserting just ```oldvalue+"0"``` if that character is ```0``` and both ```oldvalue+"0"``` and ```oldvalue+"00"``` if that character is ```1```. Keep two successive level sets at each stage and return the last one.

Comment: I'm not sure how it will work. If I build the string from scratch and every "1" in bin is `oldvalue+"00"` (is `oldvalue` currently being built?), then I will end up with string only with "00". Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Let’s suppose that after dealing with the nth character of bin you have a set (currentSet) containing all combinations thus far. Now you deal with the (n+1)th character: take each string from currentSet  and insert the one (if the character is 0) or two (if the character is 1) possible strings into newSet. Keep doing that, copying newSet to currentSet and then clearing newSet before you compound each character.

Comment: And another method entirely would be to construct your strings recursively in a tree-like approach, since at each character of bin you either add just a 0 (if that character of bin were 0) or the two possibilities 00 or 1 (if that character of bin were 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally your combinations are built up like a tree. The units are either

```
    (0)               (1)
    / \       or      / \
   0                 1   00
```

where (.) signifies what was in the original binary string and the strings at the bottom are what you would add as a result.

So, like any binary search tree you can either do the equivalent of BFS (breadth-first-search): deal with all the possibilities at one level before moving to the next, or DFS (depth-first-search): recursively work down each branch to the bottom to insert a new combination string.

The two approaches are illustrated for your problem in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

//======================================================================

set<string> BFS( const string &str )
{
   set<string> result;
   if ( str.length() == 0 ) return result;

   result.insert( str.substr( 0, 1 ) );   if ( str[0] == '1' ) result.insert( "00" );
   for ( int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++ )
   {
      auto last = result;   result.clear();
      for ( const string &s : last )
      {
         result.insert( s + str[i] );
         if ( str[i] == '1' ) result.insert( s + "00" );
      }
   }
   return result;
}

//======================================================================

void DFS( const string &left, const string &right, set<string> &result )
{
   if ( right.length() == 0 )
   {
      result.insert( left );
   }
   else
   {
      DFS( left + right[0], right.substr( 1 ), result );
      if ( right[0] == '1' ) DFS( left + "00", right.substr( 1 ), result );
   }
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   string str;
   cout << "Enter a binary string: ";   cin >> str;

   cout << "BFS:\n";
   for ( const string &s : BFS( str ) ) cout << s << '\n';

   cout << "\nDFS:\n";
   set<string> result;
   DFS( "", str, result );
   for ( string s : result ) cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output for 1111

```
BFS:
00000000
0000001
0000100
000011
0010000
001001
001100
00111
1000000
100001
100100
10011
110000
11001
11100
1111

DFS:
00000000
0000001
0000100
000011
0010000
001001
001100
00111
1000000
100001
100100
10011
110000
11001
11100
1111
```